# Regular Expression find/replace

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge list of numbers such as 123456 that I have to change into:
,'123456'. How can I do this in word or excel?

Thanks

Comment: What's the ultimate goal?  Are you trying to create a list of strings? For instance you have these numbers in a list (backslash means next row) `123 / 2345 / 2918 / ...`.  In the end, are you trying to put all these in a single list, `'123', '2345', '2918', ...`?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> does the trick. Is built in in excel and word.

In Excel you can e.g. mark only one column or one row and do then your replacement with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> . That way you keep other columns/ rows untouched.

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl+H?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have a long column of these numbers in column A of an Excel worksheet, starting with cell A1.

In cell B1, enter `=",'"&A1&"'"`

Then autofill down: select cell B1, hover over the square that appears at the bottom-right corner of the cell, and double-click. (If you have any gaps in the column of numbers, you may need to drag down on the square instead.)

Now right-click on the column heading and choose `Copy`, then right-click again and choose `Paste Values`.

Answer (score 0):

just use the find and replace function that is built into excel.

Comment: you may have to play around with the custom format option, to enable excel to have a quotation (') mark at the beginning of the number

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

Select the cells you wish to change and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = ",'" & r.Value & "'"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Which will produce:

[image]

Each cell gets a prefix of *comma quote* and a suffix of *quote*.